# copying data with ldm/stm instructions

Tags: assembly, arm

It's arm assembler. I need to copy 8 words of array in one iteration by using instructions ldm and stm. You are not allowed to add or clear any line of code. How do I do this?

This is the code you need to use:

```
  num   EQU 24      
  IMPORT exit       
  EXPORT start          

start   LDR r0, =src
        LDR r1, =dst
        MOV r2, #num
            LSL     r2,#3
LOOP    LDM ????                        what to put instead of ????                     
        STM ????                   
        SUBS    r2, r2, #1
        BNE LOOP        
        BL exit         
        AREA Block, DATA, READWRITE
 src    DCD 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
 dst    DCD 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
END
```

Comment: Is this some kind of homework?

Comment: I'm preparing my exam. But,I'm also very curious about this.

Comment: have you read the arm documentation for these instructions including the pseudo code that describes how it works?  You simply put a register list, you indicate what happens to the base register (increment after/before, decrement after/before) and is that register written back after.  Etc.

Comment: You are asking us to help you with your exam? Shouldn't you ask your instructor instead?

Comment: Yes,I should,but the exam is in several hours,so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a description of `LDM` and `STM` [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Cihcadda.html).

The instructions you're looking for are probably `LDMIA` and `STMIA` (`IA` means increment after; i.e. transfer one word, then increment the address).

For example:

```
LDMIA r0!,{r3-r6}  @ Read four words from src (r0) into registers r3, r4, r5 and r6.
                   @ The final address is written back to r0.
```

---

By the way, this doesn't look quite right to me:

```
     MOV r2, #num, LSL#2
LOOP ...               
     SUBS r2, r2, #1
```

From the looks of things, you're iterating 96 times (== the size of the array in bytes). But you're obviously not just copying a single byte per iteration. If you're planning to copy 8 words per iteration you should only iterate 3 times (96/32).

Comment: no,num is set to 24, not 0x24, but you are right that shifting is not correct, it should be LSR#3. Anyway,I know how ldm and stm work, but I can't figure out how to solve the problem I've written. And,yes,I'm not copying bytes but words that are 4B long.

Comment: 24 (decimal) LSL 2 is 96 (decimal). My example with `LDMIA` shows you exactly how to do the load, except that the register list would be `r3-r10` if you're copying 8 words per iteration. Then you just `STMIA` the same register list to `r1`.

Comment: memory representation is the same,zeros and ones,so shifting's ok...  See,the problem is how to get data into those registers r3-r10 if you can't add any more lines in the code I've given.

Comment: You'd use `LDMIA`, just as I showed (and as they show in the documentation I linked to).

Comment: Yeah,I can see it now.I was so confused,really don't know why...